# No me está actualizando el console.log en la consola de chrome

Tags: javascript, consola

estoy arrancando a practicar un poco con js y me estoy consiguiendo con el problema que no se me actualiza los comando del console.log en la consola. El alert funciona lo que descarto que esté mal enlazado. Muchas gracias a todos lo que puedan tirar ideas.

Comment: Si tan solo agregas tu código para verificar y ayudarte, estaría mucho mejor. Te recomiendo hacer el [tour] y luego lee [ask] para saber cómo funciona este sitio. Luego te servira mucho para nuevas preguntas

Comment: Pon el console.log antes del alert, a ver si así llegas a el.  Como no has puesto tu código no sabemos si después del alert haces algo más que quizás da error e impide que se vea el console.log() al cual parece que no llegas